# How to keep asynchronously uploaded files of a form in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Here's the scenario:

1. I have a website developed with **ASP.NET MVC**, there is a form in the website that contains multiple input fields including several **file** upload fields.
2. What I am trying to do is have the **files** **uploaded asynchronously** as soon as user selects a file, so that while the file is being uploaded user can continue filling in other inputs.
3. Once the server has **received** **&** **verified** the files are valid, when user clicks the submit button the form will be sent and saved **along with the uploaded files**.

I would assume that I need to have a **separate controller action** that deals with the asynchronous upload, but then how would I access these uploaded files from a **different action** (within the same controller) that handles the **form submission**?

If I need to **temporarily store** the files until the form is submitted, where would be the desirable place to store it?

Comment: There are some jquery plugins that will do this, but you can also use ajax with `FormData` to upload your files and in the method your calling, save the files to a directory and return the path you saved it to (and perhaps update a hidden field with that path so when you submit the form, you know where the file is). Not sure why you would want to send the files again when you submit the form - you should probably be just clearing the file input and displaying the file name in the success callback so the user knows its been uploaded.

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke thanks for the suggestion. So currently all my files are uploaded synchronously along with other form data on submit. This way my form model is bound correctly to the controller (all the text fields and files). However it seems like you are suggesting that I pass the path of the uploaded files on submit. Would this mean that I have to change my form model to store path `strings` instead of `HttpPostedFile` in order for the binding to work?

Comment: Yes, if you want to save the files before you have save the object, you would need to return the path of the the saved file(s) so that you can then add that property to your database when you save the object. You will probably also want some method of being able to delete a file once its been saved to your temp location in case the user made a mistake.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks for the advice! Mind posting it briefly as an answer so others can reference your advice as well? Cheers.

Comment: The question is a bit broad and a full answer would run into many pages. I'll have a think and perhaps add an answer in a few hours with the basic steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems no point uploading the files when you submit the form if you have already uploaded them when you select the form (and you will probably want to remove the `enctype` attribute from your form element.

The basic steps would be to upload a file when the user selects it with ajax (using `FormData`), save it and return the path to that file so that when you finally submit the form, you can post that information as well.

Start by defining view models to represent what you want to display/edit in the view

```
public class FileAttachmentVM
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    .... // properties to display/edit in the view
    public List<FileAttachmentVM> Files { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    <div id="file-inputs"></div> // placeholder for the file collection hidden inputs
}
<div id="file-names"></div> // place holder for the collection of file already uploaded
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button type="button" id="upload">Upload</button>
// template for adding new inputs for the file collection
<div id="template" style="display:none">
    <div class="file-details">
        <input type="hidden" class="file-path" name="Files[#].Path" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" class="file-name" name="Files[#].DisplayName" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="Files.Index" value="#" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script to upload the file and update the DOM

```
var fileInputs = $('#file-inputs');
var fileNames = $('#file-names');

$('#Upload').click(function () {
    var file = $('#file').get(0).files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "...")',// add controller name
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                // Oops, something went wrong
                return;
            }
            $('#file').val(''); // clear file input
            // Add the display name
            fileNames.append($('<div></div>').text(data.DisplayName));
            // Add the inputs
            var index = (new Date()).getTime(); // unique indexer
            var clone = $('#template').clone(); // clone the template
            clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/#/g, index)); // update the indexer
            fileInputs.append(clone.html()); // append the inputs
            // update the input values
            var lastFile = fileInputs.find('.file-details').last();
            lastFile.find('.file-path').last().val(data.Path);
            lastFile.find('.file-name').last().val(data.DisplayName);
        }
    });
});
```

and finally the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var displayName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(displayName);
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), fileExtension);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        return Json(new { DisplayName = displayName, Path = path });
    }
    return Json(null);
}
```

and then in the controller method that you submitting the form to

```
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
{
    // Initialize a data model, map the view model properties to it and save
    // Loop through model.Files and save each file display name and path to the database (along with the ID of the entity you created/updated
```

A few notes about the code.

1. You indicated you want *files uploaded as soon as user selects a
   file*. IMO, that's not expected behavior it would be better to allow
   the user to explicitely check and then click an upload button, but
   you could modify the script to handle the file inputs `.change()`
   event rather than the buttons `.click()` event.
2. The files are saved with a `Guid` to ensure they are unique and
   there is no risk of a file being overwritten if another user uploads
   a file with the same name.
3. You would need to consider what happens if a user has uploaded some
   files but then abandons the edit. For example you could save them
   into a temporary directory and in the form submit method, move them
   to a permanent directory (and periodically remove any abandoned
   files)
4. You may want to also include a 'delete' link adjacent the display
   name in case the user changes their mind (that link would call an
   ajax method to delete the file).